# multi-thread applications in Berkeley DB

Tags: database, multithreading, berkeley-db

I have a simple multi-threaded application. All the threads will only do put operations to the same database. But before a thread takes a put operations, it will first of all acquire a mutex lock to increase the key number and then release the lock and then do the put operation, i.e., the threads will insert items with different key number maybe at the same time. That's what I did in my application.

What I am still confused about is whether this simple app needs to specify DB_INIT_LOCK flag or DB_INIT_CDB flag? I have read the document about these flags. DB_INIT_CDB means multiple reads/single writer, however, in my simple app, the threads can operate concurrently, not single writer, so I do not need it. For DB_INIT_LOCK, since the threads never insert the item with the same key, I do not need it, am I right?

Please correct me if I am wrong. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly state that `DB_INIT_CDB` gives you a multi-reader, single-writer environment.  This puts Berkeley DB in a completely different mode of operation.  But, since you've got more than one writer, you can't use it.

You'll need at least these two flags:

**DB_INIT_LOCK:** You're doing your own locking around your database key generation.  But when you insert records into the database, Berkeley DB is going to touch some of the same pieces of memory.  For example, the very first two records you insert will be right next to each other in the database.  Unless they are large, they'll be on the same database "page" of memory.  You need this flag to tell BDB to do its own locking.

It's the same as if you implemented your own in-memory binary tree that multiple threads were changing.  You'd have to use some kind of locking to prevent the threads from completely destroying the tree with incompatible updates.

**DB_THREAD:** This flag lets BDB know that multiple threads will be using the same database environment.

You may find that you need to use transactions, or at the very least to allow BDB to use them interally.  That's `DB_INIT_TXN`.  And, I've always needed `DB_INIT_MPOOL` and `DB_PRIVATE` to allow BDB to use `malloc()` to manage some of its own memory.

(Just as an aside, if you have a simple increment for your key, consider using an atomic increment operation instead of a mutex.  If you're using C with gcc, the builtin `__sync_fetch_and_add` (or `__sync_add_and_fetch`) can do this for you.  From C++, you can use std::atomic's post-increment.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's very likely that the very first two records inserted are on the same page in db. However, I have read that "the access methods except Queue do page-level locking". Here is the [link](http://www.mtholyoke.edu/~mcrowley/perl-tmp/docs.db277/ref/am/pagesize.html). So in my opinion, if I have set the access method to be Btree, then BDB helps me do page-level locking automatically. I do not need to specify DB_INIT_LOCK in this scenario.

Comment: The Berkeley DB documentation can be confusing, for sure.  That link is technically correct - it does page level locking.  But, I can tell you from experience that it certainly doesn't do it automatically.  You'll need DB_INIT_LOCK to enable it.  But, you'll find out pretty quickly once you try the database out with multiple threads!  :)